# Extract first n bytes from .tar.gz and output as a .tar.gz in a single command

Tags: pipe, tar, dd, compression, gzip

I have a .tar.gz as input and want to extract the first 128 MiB of it and output as a .tar.gz in a single command. I tried:

```
sudo tar xzOf input.tar.gz | sudo dd of=output bs=1M count=128 iflag=fullblock | sudo tar -cfz final.tar.gz -T -
```

which is obviously not working. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` on second and third command? Try second `tar` to be `tar czf....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract the archive’s contents (which can’t work here — there’s no way to track the individual files’ metadata), decompress it, truncate it and recompress it. If you have a version of `head` capable of this:

```
gzip -dc input.tar.gz | head -c128M | gzip -c > final.tar.gz
```

or you can use `dd` as in your command:

```
gzip -dc input.tar.gz | dd bs=1M count=128 iflag=fullblock | gzip -c > final.tar.gz
```